# Copy one row from one table to another

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I need a little help and I can’t find an answer. I would like to replicate a row from one data table to another. My code is:

```
public function getClone($id) {
 $item = Post::find($id);
 $clone = $item->replicate();
 unset($clone['name'],$clone['price']);
 $data = json_decode($clone, true);
 Order::create($data);

 $orders = Order::orderBy('price', 'asc')->paginate(5);
 return redirect ('/orders')->with('success', 'Success');
}
```

and i got an  error :

> "Missing argument 1 for
>   App\Http\Controllers\OrdersController::getClone()"

.
I have two models: `Post` and `Order`. After trying to walk around and write something like this:

```
public function getClone(Post $id) {
...
}
```

I got another error

> Method replicate does not exist.

Where‘s my mistake? What wrong have i done? Maybe i should use another function? Do i need any additional file or code snippet used for  json_decode ?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what exactly you want to do. `Missing argument 1` means, that you're not passing the ID to your `getClone()` method.

Comment: Actually i have two tables:”posts” (method “Post”) and “orders” (method “Order”). Both of them has the same fields. “Posts” table has a lot of rows. Besides CRUD buttons, there is one more button – “Order”. When I press this button, I want this record to be copied to “Orders” table, so, my route is : Route::post('/orders','OrdersController@getClone'); cause I want localhost:8000/orders to be displayed after pressing “Order” button in localhost:8000/posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure your controller gets the **$id** parameter - you can read more about how routing works in Laravel here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing

```
Route::get('getClone/{id}','YourController@getClone');
```

Then, call the URL that contains the ID, e.g.:

```
localhost:8000/getClone/5
```

If you want to create an **Order** object based on a **Post** object, the following code will do the trick:

```
public function getClone($id) {
  // find post with given ID
  $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
  // get all Post attributes
  $data = $post->attributesToArray();
  // remove name and price attributes
  $data = array_except($data, ['name', 'price']);
  // create new Order based on Post's data
  $order = Order::create($data);

  return redirect ('/orders')->with('success', 'Success');
```

}

Comment: In this situation I’m still getting missing argument error for getClone() :(

Comment: Just fix the routing like in the other answer and my answer in the getClone() method. You won't need a replicate() method this way - it should be used to get a copy of the same model, not another one.

Comment: You were still missing the $id parameter from the routing, I've updated the answer. I've removed one line that fetches orders from the database, as you weren't using this variable anywhere in the controller.

Comment: THANK YOU very much for pointing me to the right way. Now i‘m getting what i really need...with small correction – i changed „Route::get...“ to „Route::post...“, ‘cause with „get“ i‘m getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251) error.
Thank You once again for Your time (:

Comment: Ok, didn't know you were using POST for that, the method name was confusing :) Could you please mark the question as answered then?

Answer (score 0):

By writing

```
public function getClone(Post $id)
```

you are telling the script that this function needs a variable $id from class Post, so you can rewrite this code like this :

```
public function getClone(){
  $id = new Post;
}
```

However, in your case this does not make any sence, because you need and integer, from which you can find the required model.
To make things correct, you should look at your routes, because the url that executes this function is not correct, for example, if you have defined a route like this :

```
Route::get('getClone/{id}','YourController@getClone');
```

then the Url you are looking for is something like this :

```
localhost:8000/getClone/5
```

So that "5" is the actual ID of the post, and if its correct, then Post::find($id) will return the post and you will be able to replicate it, if not, it will return null and you will not be able to do so.

```
$item = Post::find($id);
if(!$item){
  abort(404)
}
```

Using this will make a 404 page not found error, meaning that the ID is incorrect.

Comment: Your code as alone works perfect, thanks, but after trying to replicate, I’m getting the same error about method replicate non-existence. Actually i have two tables:”posts” (method “Post”) and “orders” (method “Order”). Both of them has the same fields. “Posts” table has a lot of rows. Besides CRUD buttons, there is one more button – “Order”. When I press this button, I want this record to be copied to “Orders” table, so, my route is : Route::post('/orders','OrdersController@getClone'); cause I want localhost:8000/orders to be displayed after pressing “Order” button in localhost:8000/posts